# Quotient groups and product groups

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups

I am new to group theory. However, I came across this notation,

$$ SU(2)\cong SL(2,\mathbb{R})\otimes SL(2,\mathbb{R})/\mathbb{Z}_2$$

You can assume that I am aware of what each group individually means. Thank you very much.

Comment: See https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Tensor_product_of_groups

Comment: Are you asking what $\otimes$ means?